# Number of repetitions of modular operation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I am looking into a problem that is about threaded pins on a circle. See image bellow for an example:
[image]

I approached it as follows:
Let $P$ be the number of pins and $G$ the number of gaps.
Number the pins on the circle from $0$ to $(P-1)$. The process of moving the thread from pin to pin is just a modulo operation on $P$. I.e. for $5$ pins and gap of $2$ we connect:
$0$ with $2$ i.e. $(0+2)\space mod \space 5$
$2$ with $4$ i.e. $(2 + 2)\space mod\space 5$
$4$ with $1$ i.e. $(4 + 2)\space mod\space5$
$1$ with $3$ i.e. $(1 + 2)\space mod\space5$
$3$ with $0$ i.e. $(3 + 2)\space mod\space 5$

That requires 1 thread since we reached 0. This process can be applied to all the rest of the configurations.

For 6 pins and 2 gaps we connect:
$0$ with $2$ i.e. $(0 + 2)\space mod \space 6$
$2$ with $4$ i.e. $(2 + 2)\space mod \space 6$
$4$ with $0$ i.e. $(4 + 2)\space mod \space 6$
That was thread $1$ and we start again with pin $1$ since we got back to pin $0$.
We connect:
$1$ with $3$ i.e. $(1 + 2)\space mod \space 6$
$3$ with $5$ i.e. $(3 + 2)\space mod \space 6$
$5$ with $1$ i.e. $(5 + 2)\space mod \space 6$
That was thread $2$. I.e. we need $2$ threads as $2$ repeats of the process happened.

So each time we just wrap around the modulo $P$ and increment by $1$ and start over. The number of repetitions equals the number of threads

My problem is how to formalize the process in a way to shows that the number of threads increments based on this modulo operation.

Note: There is a post about the same problem here: [Threaded pins](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930511/how-to-approach-this-question-from-thinking-mathematically-considering-the-solut) but my question is different.

I do understand the solution about using the greatest common divisor. What I am looking for is how could I extend the modulo process I have described to reach the solution. Or is gcd also related in this approach too?

Comment: Is there anything I can do to improve the question to get some response?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your final question is no - it is a nicely presented question.

Your modulo method returns to $0$ when $$0,G,2G,3G,...,kG$$ reaches $0$ i.e. $$kG\equiv 0\pmod P.$$

This requires $$k=\frac{P}{\gcd(P,G)}.$$

Therefore the number of threads you require is $$\frac{P}{k}=\gcd(P,G).$$

Thus the methods are the same.

Comment: It is not clear to me how the `Therefore the number of threads you require is` is deduced. E.g. for 6Pins/2-Gap we have for $G$ in your notation: $0, 2, 4, 6$ and $6 = 2*3$ i.e. $k = 3$. Right? But so far there is not count of the $1, 3, 5, 1$ which is the second thread. And the thread count is $2$ and not $3$. Thread-1: $0-2-4-0$ and Thread-2: $1-3-5-1$. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: $P=6, G=2$ so gcd=2. Then k=3 which is right. Finally, the number of threads is indeed

Comment: $2$ which agrees with gcd (P,G).

Comment: Yes you are right. I am somehow having difficulty undestanding the meaning of $k$. It seems that $k$ is a multiple of $G$ such that it is a multiple of $P$ also since $kG \equiv 0 (mod P)$? Would it be possible to elaborate a bit on $k$ please?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what you say. It is therefore the number of pins per thread. In your example, k=3, means that there are three pins per thread:-0-2-4 and 1-3-5.